# Matlab GUI select which axes to plot

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I am using the code below to plot data from the serial port. Since I have two axes for plotting, how can I select a particular axes for this plot? 
From similar problem, I found that they use axes(handles.axes2);. Since I have the plot declared at the start of the program, where should I place this line of code? I tried placing it before specifying the plot title etc. but it is not working.

```
% Serial Data Logger
% Yu Hin Hau
% 7/9/2013
% **CLOSE PLOT TO END SESSION

clear
clc

%User Defined Properties 
serialPort = 'COM5';            % define COM port #
plotTitle = 'Serial Data Log';  % plot title
xLabel = 'Elapsed Time (s)';    % x-axis label
yLabel = 'Data';                % y-axis label
plotGrid = 'on';                % 'off' to turn off grid
min = -1.5;                     % set y-min
max = 1.5;                      % set y-max
scrollWidth = 10;               % display period in plot, plot entire data log if <= 0
delay = .01;                    % make sure sample faster than resolution

%Define Function Variables
time = 0;
data = 0;
count = 0;

%Set up Plot
plotGraph = plot(time,data,'-mo',...
                'LineWidth',1,...
                'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
                'MarkerFaceColor',[.49 1 .63],...
                'MarkerSize',2);

title(plotTitle,'FontSize',25);
xlabel(xLabel,'FontSize',15);
ylabel(yLabel,'FontSize',15);
axis([0 10 min max]);
grid(plotGrid);

%Open Serial COM Port
s = serial(serialPort)
disp('Close Plot to End Session');
fopen(s);

tic

while ishandle(plotGraph) %Loop when Plot is Active

    dat = fscanf(s,'%f'); %Read Data from Serial as Float

    if(~isempty(dat) && isfloat(dat)) %Make sure Data Type is Correct        
        count = count + 1;    
        time(count) = toc;    %Extract Elapsed Time
        data(count) = dat(1); %Extract 1st Data Element         

        %Set Axis according to Scroll Width
        if(scrollWidth > 0)
        set(plotGraph,'XData',time(time > time(count)-scrollWidth),'YData',data(time > time(count)-scrollWidth));
        axis([time(count)-scrollWidth time(count) min max]);
        else
        set(plotGraph,'XData',time,'YData',data);
        axis([0 time(count) min max]);
        end

        %Allow MATLAB to Update Plot
        pause(delay);
    end
end

%Close Serial COM Port and Delete useless Variables
fclose(s);
clear count dat delay max min plotGraph plotGrid plotTitle s ...
        scrollWidth serialPort xLabel yLabel;


disp('Session Terminated...');
```

Comment: As a side note, you can use `drawnow` rather than `pause` to force a re-draw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick to get reliable plotting and manipulation is to *always specify the parent  explicitly* using the [`Parent` parameter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html#property_parent) when creating a `plot` or any other graphics object. All graphics objects support this parameter.

```
hax = axes();
plot(x,y, 'Parent', hax);
```

The other alternative, as suggested by [@matlabgui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310103/matlab-gui-select-which-axes-to-plot/36310193#comment60243794_36310193) is to specify the parent axes as the first input to `plot`:

```
plot(hax, x, y);
```

I personally prefer to use the `Parent` parameter as a parameter value pair though, as that behavior is consistent across *all* graphics objects.

You should also specify the axes handle when using other functions which operate on an axes.

```
xlabel(hax, 'XLabel')
ylabel(hax, 'YLabel')
title(hax, 'This is a title')
axis(hax, [0 0 1 1])
grid(hax, 'on')
hold(hax, 'on')
```

This is particularly important if you are dealing with an interactive GUI as the user could easily click on a different axes in the middle of your plotting causing the value of `gca` to change unexpectedly. Also changing the current axes (using `axes(hax)`) can cause a poor user experience.

## Summary

For your specific code, this would involve changing your initial `plot` call:

```
plotGraph = plot(time,data,'-mo',...
                 'LineWidth',1,...
                 'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
                 'MarkerFaceColor',[.49 1 .63],...
                 'MarkerSize',2, ...
                 'Parent', handles.axes2);
```

I would also recommend adding explicit axes handles to your calls to: `grid`, `title`, `axis`, `xlabel`, and `ylabel` to ensure that their target is the axes you want.

Comment: The `plot` command accepts the parent as the 1st argument so you can also do `plot ( hax, x, y )`

Comment: @matlabgui Yes that's true. I just prefer to always specify it as a param/value since that it consistent across *all* graphics.

Comment: @TheBeginner It looks ok but look at my examples above for `xlabel`, `axis`, etc. Particularly for `axis` and `grid` you need to specify the axes handle as the *first* input rather than the `'Parent', hax` format.

Comment: @Suever I did the following. Is it correct `plotGraph = plot(time,data,'Parent', handles.axes6);         
title(plotTitle,'FontSize',25,'Parent', handles.axes6);
xlabel(xLabel,'FontSize',15,'Parent', handles.axes6);
ylabel(yLabel,'FontSize',15,'Parent', handles.axes6);
axis([0 10 min max],'Parent', handles.axes6);
grid(plotGrid,'Parent', handles.axes6);` . An arror is showing for the axis and grip. What am I doing wrong? Also, when plotting other graphs, do I use the same format, i.e ....Parent', handles.axes3) ?

Comment: @TheBeginner see my comment just above yours about `axis` and `grid`.  Also, yes, this will work for *all* plots.